# How to xor just the specified bits in a list

Tags: python, bitmap, cryptography, pattern-matching, xor

**Context:** [Image: XOR first and second, to form heart-shaped pixel art](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbwV5.jpg)

I am creating a visual one-time-pad program which splits the input bitmap into two different random lists of bits which, when XOR-ed together, should reproduce the input bitmap - kind of a "reverse-reverse-engineering".

As a highly-simplified explanation, each newly-created bitmap is given to 2 independent recipients. They may trust each other if theirs combine to form a specified shape (see below).

In my example above, the pixel inputs - and eventual output - form a heart-shape in the middle.

---

**Attempt:** Originally, my code successfully assigned appropriate bits to two separate lists, depending on whether the input bit was zero or one. (The randomness was included since I wanted different outputs to work with each time.) This was all fine when the input simply showed just a black (i.e string of 1s) heart on a white background: [Image: binary representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iyb9.jpg)

```
input_pixels = [[0,0, ... 0], [0,0, ... 0], ... , [0,1, ... 1,0]]  ## I've shortened here

bitmap1 = []
bitmap2 = []

for row in input_pixels:
    temp1 = []
    temp2 = []

    for bit in row:
        ## 'Case A' when a bit in input_pixels is 0
        if bit == 0:
            randbit = random.choice((0, 1))
            temp1.append(randbit)
            if randbit == 1:
                temp2.append(1)
            else:
                temp2.append(0)

        ## 'Case B' when a bit in input_pixels is 1
        else:
            randbit = random.choice((0, 1))
            temp1.append(randbit)
            if randbit == 1:
                temp2.append(0)
            else:
                temp2.append(1)

    bitmap1.append(temp1)
    bitmap2.append(temp2)
```

However, if the input contained 1s in areas other than the heart-shape, my code obviously wouldn't produce the desired result, since the conditionals don't discriminate between "shapes" as we perceive them.

---

**Question:** How can I change the code to possibly identify the bits of my specified shape, and only apply 'Case B' to such corresponding parts? I am not very familiar with regex, but will that perhaps solve these edge cases?

**EDIT (*clarification*):**

My code fails when for e.g: [Image: If the 1s occupy non-heart-shaped locations just **to add noise**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCpNC.png)
Although I can choose the input so that only the heart == 1 (like the image labelled 'binary repr.' above), in such cases users can immediately see, without having to resort to XOR-ing, that the bitmap they received will form a heart - which I would like to avoid. Therefore, I need to somehow apply 'Case B' to *just* the desired 'specified' area, the heart, given any noisy input.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are asking.  Your code appears to do what you want it to do for a proper `input_pixels`.  What do you mean by having the code "identify bits of specified shape?"  The input shape is fully specified by your `input_pixels`?

Comment: @JeffH `input_pixels` is indeed fixed, but I'd like to apply Case B to just the desired heart-shape, and Case A to the rest of the black pixels strewn about as noise; please see my edit for more detail on why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you would like random noise around the heart, but just using `temp2.append(random.choice((0, 1))` independent of the value of `randbit` would do it (for case A exclusively, if `0` means white and the heart is black).

Two random bits XOR'ed together still generate a random bit value, after all.

Comment: Cheers; random noise had to be added, since a recipient (or rather, an adversary) can easily deduce which bitmap corresponds to the heart-forming share due to the nature of XOR

Comment: If you have a truly random bitmap and XOR it with the original picture then the result will be *as random*, and neither bitmap *on its own* should give **any** information about the heart shape. Many key sharing schemes rely on exactly this principle. So I guess you're assuming the wrong things.

Comment: Ah, of course, I now realise your method is much easier; thanks. My method does work, only it required the highly unconventional step of splitting the original picture into 2 separate bitmaps (adding in the randomised sprinkles at this stage)